# Joda DateTime doesn't display correct time for a specific timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In a chat application, the server gave me this info regarding on the date that the message was created

`2015-05-04 09:56:27`

`DateTime` instance gives me this `2015-05-04T09:56:27.000+08:00`

What I wanted to display on the chat bubble is this format

`hh:mm a`

My code doesn't seem to display the hours and minutes I wanted, instead it displays the hours and minutes in UTC

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(strDate);

String str = String.format("%s:%s %s",
        dt.toString("hh"),
        dt.toString("mm"),
        dt.toString("a")
);
```

it displays like this `09:56 am` instead of `5:56 pm`. It seems like the +8 offset wasn't counted.  I have tried the `withOffsetParsed` and it doesn't work too

```
DateTimeFormatter df = formatter.withOffsetParsed();
DateTime dt2 = df.parseDateTime(strDate);
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: What's the TimeZone of the server? See `+08:00` at the end of `2015-05-04T09:56:27.000**+08:00**`, this is likely your TimeZone offset

Answer (score 0):

If DateTime outputs `09:56:27.000+08:00`, then that is your local time- and the UTC time is 1:56am.

However, if your expectation that this should output 5:56pm is correct, something else is wrong. The server is giving you a timestamp without a timezone specified, which is a bad API. Presumably this time should be interpreted as UTC?

Try adding `.withZoneUTC()` to the creation of the DateTimeFormatter. This will make it interpret the time fields of the string as UTC and should produce a DateTime of `09:56:27.000Z`. You'll then need to convert this is a DateTime in your local timezone to display it, by calling `.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())` (or whatever means you have to get the appropriate timezone for the user, for example)

(You could be pedantic and call `parseLocalDateTime` to get a LocalDateTime since that is what the server is sending, but personally I'd just encapsulate the UTC rule into the formatter and pull a full DateTime straight out)